# Notification fake assertion not working on password reset test?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-testing, laravel-factory

I was trying to make tests for my auth routes. For password reset route I am trying to make in which I am faking the notification module of laravel and asserting as per the docs.
This is my test file

```
 public function testUserReceivesAnEmailWithAPasswordResetLink()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        Notification::fake();

        $user = factory(User::class)->make();

        $response = $this->post($this->passwordEmailPostRoute(), [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ]);

        $this->assertNotNull($token = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $user->email));

        Notification::assertSentTo($user, PasswordReset::class);

    }
```

While I am running this, I am getting `notification was not sent` error.

My User model is like this:

```
 use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, SoftDeletes, Uuidable, Switchable, ResourceMapper;

 public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role');
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company');
    }

    public function AauthAccessToken()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OauthAccessToken');
    }

    public function isRole($role)
    {
        return $this->role->uuid == $role;
    }

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new PasswordReset($token));
    }

    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

I can't figure whats the exact problem.

Comment: What is the value of `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in your `phpunit.xml` file?

Comment: It is 'sync'. Guess I have to change it to 'database' right?

Comment: You can try, but I don't think it will help. Could you perhaps post the code where you call `sendPasswordResetNotification` from? If you remove `Notification::fake();` can you see that the notification has been sent?

Comment: I changed it to database and it worked. But the thing is its really working behind the scenes or not?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overwriting `sendPasswordResetNotification` inside your `User` model, then make sure both `User.php` and `test` file, are using the same `PasswordReset` class.